# Send SMS using Pi

Tags: python

I have a project, and I would like to send SMS message from Pi to my number phone, when I run it the command says:

cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

I used SMS gateways to send this message. There are no errors in syntax when I run the program.

Could you help me to figure out this issue?

I really appreciate that.

Comment: need more info please. what gateway? or what does your script look like? how do you run it? perl? php?

Comment: I guess your script returns '0' when successful send, so your script may have errors but does not output because it throws 'exited with non-zero status'